# Polymorphism, Autoboxing, and Implicit Conversions

Tags: java, scala, polymorphism, autoboxing, implicit-conversion

Would you consider autoboxing in Java to be a form of polymorphism?  Put another way, do you think autoboxing extends the polymorphic capabilities of Java?

What about implicit conversions in Scala?

My opinion is that they are both examples of polymorphism.  Both features allow values of different data types to be handled in a uniform manner.

My colleague disagrees with me.  Who is right?

Comment: Maybe they are polymorphic in the real sense of the word: multi (poly)-formed(morph), as they can appear in differnt forms. But in programming terms this is not polymorphism... Matthieu is right :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming):

> Subtype polymorphism, almost
>   universally called just polymorphism
>   in the context of object-oriented
>   programming, is the ability of one
>   type, A, to appear as and be used like
>   another type, B.

Implicit conversions in Scala are conversions. One object gets converted to another object.

Autoboxing is the creation of an object (again, a conversion).

Therefore, these are not polymorphism.

Comment: +1 The interface must not change and the contracts of the interface fulfilled to be a polymorphic.

Answer (score 1):

I personally consider autoboxing as kind of a hack with sometimes unexpected results.

```
 Boolean b = null;
 boolean b2 = b; // oops
```

The tricky part of autoboxing is that it isn't really a cast, which (only) changes the type, but more of a value conversion.

Comment: You can set up almost any good Java IDE to highlight the occurrences of auto-unboxing (autoboxing is always safe, your example is about the reverse conversion).